# Удаленный запуск cmd через PsExec.exe

Tags: cmd, php

День добрый!

PHP скрипт выполняет диагностику нескольких серверов в сети. В частности должен определять uptime. Пытаюсь это сделать через удалённый вызов команды net stats:

```
exec("c:\\полный\\путь\\PsExec.exe \\\\10.132.xxx.xxx -u домен\\пользователь -p пароль cmd.exe /c net statistics workstation >> C:\\полный\\путь\\psexec.tmp");
```

В результате в файле psexec.tmp всего одна 1-я строка - [статистика рабочей станции для \имя]. Впечатление такое, что остальной текст обрезается. Если точно такой же вызов делаю в cmd файле - всё работает. Если открыть скрипт php напрямую, т.е. php.exe test.php - всё работает. При открытии test.php через любой обозреватель, как уже писал, в файле psexec.tmp всего одна 1-я строка:

```
[статистика рабочей станции для \\имя]
```

Для проверки пробовал заменять команду net statistics workstation на другие: dir, systeminfo - результат тот же - в файле psexec.tmp всего одна 1-я строка.

Подскажите, что и где делаю не так? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
exec("c:\\полный\\путь\\PsExec.exe \\\\10.132.xxx.xxx -u домен\\пользователь -p пароль cmd.exe /c net statistics workstation ^> C:\\полный\\путь\\psexec.tmp");
```

файл сохранится на \\10.132.xxx.xxx 
PsExec.exe не передаёт вывод выполненых программ (точно не всегда)

http://forum.sysinternals.com/write-psexec-output-to-file_topic9797.html